# Ubuntu 22.04, wayland. If wacom tablet is used, can no longer click on web browser (edge or firefox) until the tablet gets unplugged

Tags: wayland, wacom

On Ubuntu 22.04, using a multi monitor setup. The system defaults to wayland (not sure why when it seemes so buggy)

When I hover my pen over my Wacom tablet, I can no longer click on my web browsers with my mouse. This happens even if the pen is no longer anywhere near the tablet.

The only fix is to unplug the tablet.

The tablet being used is the Wacom One (non screen tablet)